# passing Double pointer in methods c

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Why when a double pointer is sent to a function as a single pointer and accessed gives no errors while trying to allocate memory there leads to segmentation fault even though allocate memory on heap.

---

**Passing double pointer to a function as double pointer argument** - works well

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    void to_fun(char **dbl_ptr)
    {
      *dbl_ptr = malloc(20);
      strcpy(*dbl_ptr,"cool");
    }
    void main( )
    {

        char **dbl_ptr = calloc ( 2 , sizeof(char *) );
        to_fun ( (dbl_ptr + 1) );
        printf("%s\n",*(dbl_ptr + 1) );
    }
```

---

**Passing double pointer to a function as single pointer argument** - seg fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void to_fun(char *dbl_ptr)
{
  dbl_ptr = malloc(20);
  strcpy(dbl_ptr,"defnitely not cool");
}
void main( )
{

    char **dbl_ptr = calloc ( 2 , sizeof(char *) );
    to_fun ( *(dbl_ptr + 1) );
    printf("%s\n",*(dbl_ptr + 1) );
}
```

---

**Passing double pointer to a function as single pointer argument** - works well

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void to_fun(char *dbl_ptr)
{
  printf("%s\n",dbl_ptr );
}
void main( )
{

    char **dbl_ptr = calloc ( 2 , sizeof(char *) );
    *(dbl_ptr + 1) = "cool";
    to_fun ( *(dbl_ptr + 1) );
}
```

---

this is just a sample code to let you get the question ..its not meant to be like improvised one blah blah blah...

I know how pointers and dereference works in depth but still this above stuff is annoying . Any one Explain why .

Comment: What is `calloc ( 2 , 1 );` supposed to do? Especially, why `2` and `1`?

Comment: What's the difference between the first and second code sample besides the different strings?

Comment: oops my bad , fixed now

Comment: C++ is a different language from C, and considerations for this sort of thing are different in C++ than in C.  Choose *one*.

Comment: Your second and third examples *do not* "Pass[ a] double pointer to a function as single pointer argument".  They pass a *single* pointer (a `char *`) to the function, which in turn expects an argument of exactly that type.

Comment: Consider `int *ip; double *dp; int **ipp`.  `ip` is an "int pointer". `dp` is a "double pointer".  `ipp` is a "pointer to an int pointer"

Comment: @JohnBollinger thats what am asking  it send  as single pointer  and expects and receives as one  and allocate memory then retain the address . which i can use it in the main

Comment: First, replace `calloc(2, 1)` with `calloc(2, sizeof(char *))` throughout, because `calloc(2, 1)` only allocates 2 bytes.

Comment: @IanAbbott thanks , Ian  I missed that one fixed  now

Comment: @WilliamPursell I know that already , By Double pointer i meant pointer to a pointer only

Comment: @mohanenb, *all* of your examples allocate memory in `main`.  If you did want to allocate in `to_fun` then that would be an appropriate use of double pointers, but if that's indeed what you want to ask about then perhaps the question text should actually mention it.

Comment: A "double pointer" is not a thing in C or C++. What you're playing with here is a "pointer to pointer".

Answer (score 3):

The first block of code works because you pass a pointer and then dereference that pointer to modify what the pointer points to (i.e. a block of memory allocated in `main`).

In the case of the second block of code, you're modifying the function parameter `dbl_ptr`.  Changes to function parameters are not reflected in the calling function since all parameters are passed by value.

The third block of code works because you're reading a function parameter and dereferencing the pointer value which points to valid memory.

Also, you're not passing a `char **` to the second and third functions but a `char *`.

You're also not allocating enough memory in `main`.  You allocate 2 bytes, but what you want is space for 2 `char *`:

```
char **dbl_ptr = calloc ( 2 , sizeof(char *) );
```

Answer (score 2):

When you want to modify a variable from inside a function, and the variable is outside the scope of the function, you pass a pointer to the variable:

```
void f(double *x) {
  *x = 12;
}

void main() {
  double z;
  f(&z);
  printf("%f", z);
}
```

When your variable is a pointer, you need a pointer to a pointer:

```
void f(double **x) {
  *x = malloc(...);
}

void main() {
  double *z;
  f(&z);
  printf("%f", z[1]);
}
```

Comment: Yes.  As easy as that.